# Define the controller namespace based on URL parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on a Web API with MVC4, and I'd like to make it backwards-compatible, as I don't control when the clients are updated.

In order to do that, I'm going to create controllers on different namespaces, something like MyApp.Controllers.v1_0.AccountsController and MyApp.Controllers.v1_1.AccountsController

Obviously, when I create both of them and try to access to an action, I get "Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Accounts'"

Then, what I tried to do is writing my own IHttpControllerActivator, so that when Create is invoked, it returns one of them... but that doesn't work b/c it never gets hit, which makes sense as Create receives an System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor that includes information about the controller it's about to use.

Also, I can't just name the controllers different (Accounts1_0Controller, Accounts1_1Controller), as when the activators returns Accounts1_0Controller, it says that its name is not "Accounts"... it probably gets its name as Accounts1_0.

Do you see any way of either:

1. Set the namespace from the url? so that I have the url /v1_0/SomeAction or /v1_1/SomeAction and it searches the controller on the appropriate namespace
2. Having multiple controllers with the same MVC name but different class name?

Hope the issue is clear enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it implementing my own IHttpControllerSelector. It's great how Microsoft made MVC4 open source, made it almost painlessly looking at their System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.

Comment: were you able to keep the help page for your API working properly? if so would you care to share your solution?